# Ensure foreground service is not cached after 30 minutes

Tags: android, foreground-service

Acording to the documentation here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle

> Services that have been running for a long time (such as 30 minutes or
> more) may be demoted in importance to allow their process to drop to
> the cached list

I have an app which is tracking, for logging purposes, user position. I am using a foreground service to keep app alive, even when not visible, and that works, but only being able to do that for 30 minutes is too little.

In my testing (mainly Huawei phone) I have to go to battery settings and explicitly allow the app to keep running in backgrounda, ang that works, but that is not really a viable solution.

How are you supposed to handle this?

Comment: use foreground service with job scheduler and keep restarting it after some time so that system doesnt black list it

Comment: Yeah, this is a real problem with no true solution. Blame Huawei, in this case, for adding an additional power saving layer that kills background processes. See [dontkillmyapp.com](https://dontkillmyapp.com/)

Comment: According to that documentation; when using a foreground service your process should be a 'visible process', and _not_ a 'service process' with the 30min demotion timer

Comment: It is a visible service, which, when it is put in the background by the user (focusing on some other app), starts the keep-alive service. Are you saying that the 30 minute limit is not relevant then?